# Functions inside "for" iteration, Python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, iteration

I am a beginner and kinda lost with the code i have written. I am writing an add-on for some software, trying to extract some data from its classes.

There is a list of statements that i am going through using operator for. I am interested in two types of statements called VC_STATEMENT_LINMOTION and VC_STATEMENT_PTPMOTION (there are many other types as well). 
First in my code i see which of these two types of statements go first. If it is LinMotion, then, i get some extract values for this LinMotion statement (by going to that function (def get_initalvalues())) till code "meets" PtpMotion statement. After it does it goes to def get_conf() function where data for PtpMotion is extracted. Also, in get_conf() if later LinMotion is met, data is taken from PtpMotion of last iteration.

But it doesnt work.

I know it sounds heavy ))). Maybe i myself made it too complicated and solution is simpler.

```
for statement in main_routine.Statements:
    if statement.Type == VC_STATEMENT_LINMOTION or statement.Type == VC_STATEMENT_PTPMOTION:


        def get_conf(*args):
            global output
            if statement.Type == VC_STATEMENT_PTPMOTION:
                ptp_motion_conf = ""
                Extracted string data is assigned to ptp_motion_conf which is later added to overall output

                output += ptp_motion_conf 
            elif statement.Type == VC_STATEMENT_LINMOTION:
                output += ptp_motion_conf #using data of VC_STATEMENT_PTPMOTION from last iteration

        def get_initialconf(*args):
            global output
            if statement.Type == VC_STATEMENT_LINMOTION:
                ...


            elif statement.Type == VC_STATEMENT_PTPMOTION:
                get_conf()        


        statements = [] # getting list of statements to know which of LinMotion or PtpMotion goes first
        for statement in main_routine.Statements:  
            statements.append(statement.Type) 

        if statements.index("LinMotion") < statements.index("PtpMotion"): #statement LinMotion goes first
            get_initialconf()  
        elif statements.index("LinMotion") > statements.index("PtpMotion"):#statement PtpMotion goes first
            get_conf()
```

i will try to show in sample:

***If LinMotions statement goes first, before PtpMotion then:***

LinMotion (some special initial data)
LinMotion (still initial data)
...
in all other LinMotion statements prog still uses initial data until PtpMotion statement appears:

PtpMotion (its own PtpMotion  data)

if LinMotion appears again, data from last PtpMotion statement is used

***If PtpMotion statement goes first, before LinMotion, then***
PtpMotion (its own PtpMotion  data)

If Linmotion appears, data from last PtpMotion statement is used

Comment: How many statements might you have? How complex will sequence of statements get?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". What doesn't happen that should? What should happen that doesn't?

Comment: "But it doesnt work." Can you explain how it doesn't work. Sure it seems a bit complex for the problem, but there is nothing obviously stupid in that code.

Comment: Well, what i get as a result is only information for LinMotion statements. For some reason, when code meets PtpMotion statements, it still extracts info for LinMotion, although it should stop and extract info from PtpMotion

Comment: And for that matter - **what are you really trying to do**? What is "lin motion" and "ptp motion"? What is a statement? What is the meaning of the output? What is the meaning of "ptp_motion_conf"?

Comment: output is global variable in which i put all the extracted information. Output variable will be saved into a file later.

Comment: @Maks: Please **update** the question to have **all** the information.  Please don't comment.  Please **update** so the question is complete.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're talking about. Describe the **format** of the "output" data. **In detail**. The same for the format of each "statement". Explain what "lin motion" is and what "ptp motion" is. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

(**Edit**: I've updated the code to reflect new information in your post.)

If I understand your problem corrrectly, a simple description of what you're trying to achieve is this: you have a list of `Statement` instances in `main_routine.Statements` and you want to perform different code based on `statement.Type`. Here is the natural structure this *usually* (read: almost always) takes in Python code.

```
# no idea what this is in your code, but since you want to save it
# to a file, I'll blindy assume it is a string.
output = ""

# current stream of statements. accumulate as long as type is compatible.
stream = []

# process each statement.
for statement in main_routine.Statements:

    if statement.Type == VC_STATEMENT_LINMOTION:
        stream.append(statement)

    elif statement.Type == VC_STATEMENT_PTPMOTION:
        if (len(stream) > 0) and (stream[-1].Type == VC_STATEMENT_LINMOTION):
            output += process_linmotion_stream(stream)
            stream = []
            continue
        stream.append(statement)

    # ignore other types of statements.

# after loop, make sure leftover statements are processed.
output += process_linmotion_stream(stream)
```

Honestly, I think everybody, not just yourself, is confused with you've written. Switch to a simple control flow that models your data and you should be fine.